# All faces duplicated

Tags: modeling

My character model's faces have somehow been duplicated. If I delete a face, there's still a face there and I need to delete the face again to see the inside of the character. And its not just one area, it's all faces.

I tried opening an earlier version of my model and I can delete the faces normally. What could have happened on why the faces are doubled? And what can I do to remove them (I tried selecting all, then Remove Doubles, but nothing happened)?

**EDIT:**

I just fuond out that its happening everytime I add and apply a Mirror modifier after having already applied one. But why is it? I already applied a Mirror initially, I want to edit the mesh again so I need to add a Mirror modifier again. The 3rd time added, faces are now quadrupled.

Comment: From the edit part of the question, probably the model is already symmetrical. So mirror adds overlapping geometry.

Comment: @lemon: Can you explain a bit more what you meant with it is already symmetrical and any idea how I can avoid this happening?

Comment: Say you have a cube (symmetrical), If you add a mirror on it, that will duplicate the 8 vertices and you'll obtain 16 (overlapping) when mirror is applied.

Comment: Yeah, are you cutting off one side before adding a mirror modifier?

Comment: The purpose of the mirror modifier is that it takes the half of your model and replicates it on the other side so you have a symmetrical mesh.  If your model already has both sides, the mirror modifier mirrors the entire object, so you end up with doubles.  In order to get what you want, you have to cut off half of your mesh, so the mirror modifier can do its part in finishing the object

Comment: Check the bisect option before applying the modifier. Might need to invert it depending on which part you worked on

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the way, you probably duplicated all faces by accident.  If that were the case, you should be able to delete them all at one time, because they're connected.  Select one of the extra faces and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.  This selects all geometry that is connected to this face.  Now you can delete it all.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, but can you take a look at the edit above in case you have an idea?